# How to extract the key of a duplicate entry error(1062) from mysql/knexjs

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, json, knex.js

I'm testing out my database by sending values from an html form.  Unique inserts are good, the connections are good.  My problem is that when I send a duplicate (username)  knowingly - again for testing purposes, I get an error message. Which is perfect!

However I want to extract the cause which happens to be the key.  The error is an object according to typeof(error). Specifically this:

Error: insert into `Users` (`password`, `role`, `username`) values ('1112131234434', 'basic', 'Cthulu') - Duplicate entry 'Cthulu' for key 'username'

1. I tried extracting the key after converting the object to json with JSON.stringify.  But the only value that saves is:
   {"code":"ER_DUP_ENTRY","errno":1062,"sqlState":"#23000"}
   What happened to the rest of the message?  Can I not convert the entire error to string?  And the do a substring search for the key?  Or am I going about this the wrong way?

2.
 Also, I wrote a function to go through the keys of the object, but this object seems to be a string and yet it isn't. I cannot seem to extract the string - specifically - this part of the string: **"'key 'username'"** of the error above.

To be clear, my goal is to send the key 'username' back to the client form to indicate that his username is taken.  I'll have to do the same with the email later on too, hence why I want the key.

edit: I believe I have to go with stored procedures with GET DIAGNOSTICS. Similar to [this article](http://www.chriscalender.com/tag/declare-exit-handler-for-sqlexception/).

Answer (score 0):

So this (I THINK) is ugly.  But the solution that I have *and it works!* is 
that I created a stored procedure (in mysql) including the GET DIAGNOSTICS command.

```
    DELIMITER //

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `insert_new_user` //
    CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_new_user` (uname VARCHAR(45), pass CHAR(96), r varchar(15))
    BEGIN
        /**
        Return field that has triggered the error, otherwise, return good
        **/
     -- Declare variables to hold diagnostics area information
      DECLARE code CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
      DECLARE msg TEXT;
      DECLARE rows INT;
      DECLARE result TEXT;
      -- Declare exception handler for failed insert
      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
          GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
            code = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, msg = MESSAGE_TEXT;
        END;

      -- Perform the insert
      INSERT INTO Users(username, password, role) VALUES (uname, pass,  'full');

      -- Check whether the insert was successful
      IF code = '00000' THEN
        GET DIAGNOSTICS rows = ROW_COUNT;
        SET result = CONCAT('insert succeeded, row count = ',rows);
      ELSE
        SET result = CONCAT('insert failed, error = ',code,', message = ',msg);
      END IF;
      -- Say what happened
    SELECT result;

    END //
```

Btw, I did copy and alter the code as needed - I wish I remembered the site...

Then in my express server I wrote a knex.raw(...) statement.  And in the

```
.then(result => { ... })
```

function (since knex is a promise) I had the result inspected for error with a call to a getError(result) function.  If it has the error, it gets me the key, in my case: 'username'. (I still have to do the alternative for no error ) i.e.

---console output---for no errors

ERR_str: [[[{"result":"insert succeeded, row count = 1"}],{"fieldCount":0,"affectedRows":0,"insertId":0,"info":"","serverStatus":2,"warning.....it goes on

---end output-------

Just for reference sake, here is the console output for when error 1062 happens

---console output---for 1062 error

ERR_str: [[[{"result":"insert failed, error = 23000, message = Duplicate entry 'leerman2' for key 'username'"}],{"fieldCount":0,"affectedRows":0,"insertId":0,"info":"","serverStatus":2,"warningStatus":0}],[[{"_b...it goes on

---end output-------

And here is the code for the key extraction:

```
    function getError(err) {
        const ERR_str = JSON.stringify(err);
        console.log(`Entered getError() function...proceeding to exctract error...`);

        console.log(`ERR_str: ${ERR_str}`);
        console.log(`Error is string. [typeOf(ERR_str)]: ${typeof(ERR_str)}. (Attempting to exctract key...`);
        const START = (ERR_str.indexOf('key')) + 'key'.length + 2; // 2 including spaces 
        console.log(`Start: ${START}`);
        const END = ERR_str.indexOf(`'"}`);
        console.log(`End: ${END}`);    
        const KEY = ERR_str.substr(START, END - START);
        console.log(`key to return to server: ${KEY}`);

        return KEY || 0;
    }
```

Not the cleanest of code, but a think a good start. I can send it now to Angular and work with it as intended.  If anyone sees anything wrong with this approach, feel free let me know.